# Upgrade to TYPO3 9.5, getting Symfony RuntimeException... Command controller class "TYPO3\CMS\Lang\Command\LanguageCommandController" does not exist

Tags: symfony, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm upgrading from TYPO3 8.7 to TYPO3 9.5 and am getting the following error. I don't see anywhere in my site extension that that controller is used and don't know what do to. This error is preventing me from using any `typo3cms` commands. Looked for answers on the Slack channel and else where but haven't found answers yet and am stuck.

- Deleted all cache via the TYPO3 Install tool GUI
- Manually deleted and rebuilt `vendor` and `typo3temp` directories.

```bash
[ Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException ]                                     
  Command controller class "TYPO3\CMS\Lang\Command\LanguageCommandController" does not exist.  
                                                                                               

Exception code: 1520200175

Exception trace:
#0 ()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/CommandConfiguration.php:102
#1 Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\CommandConfiguration::extractCommandDefinitionsFromControllers()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/CommandConfiguration.php:94
#2 Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\CommandConfiguration::unifyCommandConfiguration()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/CommandConfiguration.php:149
#3 Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\CommandConfiguration->addCommandControllerCommands()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/CommandCollection.php:141
#4 Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\CommandCollection->addCommandControllerCommands()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Core/Kernel.php:138
#5 Helhum\Typo3Console\Core\Kernel->handle()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:30
#6 {closure}()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:32
#7 require()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/typo3cms:3
```

Comment: IMO I have had similar issues... Keep in mind, removed packages are also in your `sysext`-folder. In your case, EXT:lang has been removed. Manually deleting your `public/typo3/`  might help.

Comment: You were absolutely right @JulianHofmann! Thank you so much. I had forgotten to delete the `typo3` folder and let it be recreated. Don't you think that that should be an optional part of the Install tool and `typo3cms` command line process upgrade process? Make this an answer to the question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, removed packages are also in your sysext-folder.

In your case, EXT:lang has been removed.

In my case, it has been relicts of `typo3/cms` while switching to a subtree-split installation of TYPO3.

Manually cleaning up your `web-dir` (and `root-dir` if used) by deleting your `typo3/`-folder will help.

Comment: Yes just deleting the entire `typo` directory and recreating it was the easiest solution and fixed the problem. Thank you!!!!